# How to prepare react component as external package using webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-externals

I have react component hosted on github, it is simple wrapper around `<table>` with few features. I use webpack to build my project. This is webpack config inherited after `react-create-app`:

```
module.exports = {
    bail: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        index: paths.appIndexJs
    },
    externals : {
        react: 'react'
    },
    output: {
        path: paths.appBuild,
        filename: 'index.js',
        publicPath: publicPath,
        library: "ReactSimpleTable",
        libraryTarget: "umd"
    },
    resolve: {
        fallback: paths.nodePaths,
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', '']
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            ... preloaders ...
        ],
        loaders: [
            ... loaders ...
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(env),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css'),
    ],
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    }
};
```

And now when I used my component in another project (as external package from github) I've got warnings related to that issue: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html .

If I remove `externals` from webpack config everything works fine, but my output file is about 130kB (sic!). With `externals` in webpack config react is excluded from index.js and it weights about 35kB (non minified). But I got warnings :/

I wonder how to exclude react from build and mitigate warnings. I don't use PropTypes in any unusual way, so advices from https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html are not relevant.

I just want to let users import my component and assume, that they have react already in dependencies...

Comment: Can you please share the relevant bits of code the warning is referring to?

Comment: Warning is referring to every propTypes defined in every component. Lot of warnings... :) Code is here: https://github.com/kazagkazag/react-simple-table . This is webpack config https://github.com/kazagkazag/react-simple-table/blob/master/config/webpack.config.prod.js and first component: https://github.com/kazagkazag/react-simple-table/blob/master/src/table/Table.js (I've got warnings from that component as well...).